# Como puedo capturar el nombre mientras subo archivos al servidor

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

tengo la siguiente situación. Estoy subiendo múltiples archivos al servidor pero necesito que una ves que el archivo este en el servidor me muestra el nombre del que se subió y así sucesivamente con los que siguen. El proceso lo esto haciendo mediante ajax y php . Los archivos me suben sin problema pero el mensaje que recibo es el del último archivo y no mientras están subiendo. Les dejo el código para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Gracias

HTML

```
<div id="myModalmultpl" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Subir doctumento</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <?php echo for_open('#', array('class' => 'form-signin', 'id' =>'form-polizam')); ?>
        <div id="idsubiendo"></div>
        <input type="file" name="uploadfile[]" id="uploadfile[]" multiple />
        <input type="hidden" name="tipoupload" id="tipoupload" value="1" >
        <input type="button" name="submit" id="idsubmit" value="Subir">
        <?php echo for_close(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cerrar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#idsubmit").on('click', function () {

 try {

  //obtenemos un array con los datos del archivo
  var dataString = new FormData($("#form-polizam")[0]);
  $.ajax({
   url: 'index.php?c=gpagar&f=setgdrive',
   type: 'POST',
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function () {
    $("div#idsubiendo").html('<div class="alert alert-success"><b>Subiendo ...</b></div>');
   },
   //una vez finalizado correctamente
   success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    bootbox.alert("<h6>El fichero ha sido subido al Google Drive: "+data.error+"</h6>");
   },
   //si ha ocurrido un error
   error: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("div#idsubiendo").html('');
    bootbox.alert("A ocurrido un error por favor contacte con  el administrador");
   }
  });

 } catch (err) {
  bootbox.alert(err);
 }
});
```

Php

```
   foreach($datos as $val){
     unset($_SESSION['idPol']);
     $nombre = $val['name'];
     $ext = pathinfo($nombre, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
     $aNombre = explode("-",$nombre);
     $fecha = $aNombre[0]."-".$aNombre[1]."-".$aNombre[2];
     //Traemos el id del movimiento.
     $idmov = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','', $aNombre[4]);  
     $objMov = $gpa->get_movAutoId($idmov, $fecha);
     $_SESSION['idPol'] = $objMov->id;
     //Conformamos el nombre del fichro
     $nameFile = $gpa->set_namefile($objMov->id_mov);

     $path = "lib/gdriver/files/";
     $nom = $path.$nombre;
     $nom2 = $path.$nameFile.".".$ext;
     rename($nom, $nom2);
     //Extraemos el id de la empresa.
     $obj = $emp->get_empresaNomId($aNombre[3]);
     $fileid = $gpa->set_datagdrive($nameFile.".".$ext, $obj->id, $fecha);
     $jdata['error'] = $fileid;
     echo json_encode($jdata);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya logre resolver el problema que tenia a continuación les dejo el código por si alguien lo necesita.

Gracias

Javascript

```
const input = document.getElementById('uploadfiles[]');
  if(input.files && input.files[0])
   datos = input.files;
   $.each(datos,function (index, value) {
 
    console.log(index+" "+value.name);
 
    var dataString = new FormData($("#form-polizam")[0]);
     dataString.append('uploadfile', value);
 
    $.ajax({
     url: 'index.php?c=gpagar&f=setgdrive',
     type: 'POST',
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     dataType: 'json',
     beforeSend: function () {
      $("div#idsubiendo").html('<div class="alert alert-success"><b>Subiendo ... </b></div>');
     },
     //una vez finalizado correctamente
     success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      $("div#idsubiendo").html('<div class="alert alert-success"><b>El fichero ha sido subido al Google Drive: '+data.error+' </b></div>');
     },
     //si ha ocurrido un error
     error: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      $("div#idsubiendo").html('');
      bootbox.alert("A ocurrido un error por favor contacte con  el administrador");
     }
    });
   });
```

Php

```
$datos = upload_file($config);
     unset($_SESSION['idPol']);
     $nombre = $datos['name'];
     $ext = pathinfo($nombre, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
     $aNombre = explode("-",$nombre);
     $fecha = $aNombre[0]."-".$aNombre[1]."-".$aNombre[2];
     //Traemos el id del movimiento.
     $idmov = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','', $aNombre[4]);
     $objMov = $gpa->get_movAutoId($idmov, $fecha);
     $_SESSION['idPol'] = $objMov->id;
     //Conformamos el nombre del fichro
     $nameFile = $gpa->set_namefile($objMov->id_mov);
 
     $path = "lib/gdriver/files/";
     $nom = $path.$nombre;
     $nom2 = $path.$nameFile.".".$ext;
     rename($nom, $nom2);
     //Extraemos el id de la empresa.
     $obj = $emp->get_empresaNomId($aNombre[3]);
     $fileid = $gpa->set_datagdrive($nameFile.".".$ext, $obj->id, $fecha);
     $jdata['error'] = $nameFile.".".$ext;
     echo json_encode($jdata);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te recomiendo es que cada vez que realices la subida de algun archivo respondas a tu aplicacion ejemplo:

```
foreach($_FILES["archivo"]['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
    {
        
        if($_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$key]) {
            $filename = $_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$key]; 
            $source = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"][$key]; 
            
            // SI EL ARCHIVO SE MOVIÓ DE MANERA CORRECTA RESPONDES

            if(move_uploaded_file($source, "./$filename")) {    
                echo "El archivo $filename se ha almacenado en forma exitosa.<br>";
                } else {    
                echo "Ha ocurrido un error, por favor inténtelo de nuevo.<br>";
            }
    
        }
    }
```

2.- Y ya en tu `succes` tendrias ese mensaje, recuerda que puedes responder un JSON en lugar de un cadena de texto como el que se muestra en el ejemplo anterior.